# Architecture for plugins with combined frontend/backend functionality (Vue and Express)

Tags: vue.js, express, vue-component, vue-cli

I have a single repo that has a Vue CLI generated frontend application and an Express backend application. The repo is setup as a standard Vue CLI app, with a top-level backend src folder. The Express app defines a few JSON APIs and serves the compiled Vue app's static files.

I'd like to build a plugin system for it: a plugin creates new API endpoints, but can optionally create .vue single file components for use in the frontend. These SFCs would be exposed through dynamically generated routes in the Vue Router. Eventually, the plugins would be in dedicated NPM packages.

The issue I'm running into is how to properly import these .vue components from a location outside of the frontend src tree. Currently I'm doing this:

```js
// vue.config.js

// generated dynamically with fs.readDirSync
process.env.VUE_APP_PLUGINS = JSON.stringify([{
  name: 'my-plugin',
  component: '/path/to/src-backend/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.vue'
}];
```

```js
// router.js

JSON.parse(process.env.VUE_APP_PLUGINS).forEach(plugin => {
  routes.push({
    name: plugin.name,
    path: `/plugins/${plugin.name}`,
    component: import(plugin.component)
  });
});
```

I get a frontend error with the import call: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module '/full/path/to/my-plugin.vue'`. Which makes sense, because the browser can't read from my file system.

I've also tried creating an alias in `vue.config.js`, and using a shorter alias'd module path, like so:

```js
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  // [...]
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@plugins': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src-backend/plugins')
      },
      extensions: ['vue', 'js', 'json']
    }
  }
}
```

There may be a way to solve this dependency resolve issue, but I also question if my architecture is the best approach. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue with the dynamic import failing. Webpack engine is very particular about the expression passed to `import()`. It has to be able to infer things about the beginning path and ideally file name. This was the solution:

```js
// vue.config.js

// generated dynamically with fs.readDirSync
process.env.VUE_APP_PLUGINS = JSON.stringify([{
  name: 'my-plugin',
  component: 'my-plugin-component'
}];

moduel.exports = {
  // ...

  // setup alias for cleaner path in frontend import
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@plugins': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src-backend/plugins')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// Vue router.js

JSON.parse(process.env.VUE_APP_PLUGINS).forEach(comp => {
  routes.push({
    path: `/plugins/${comp.name}/${comp.component}`,
    name: `${comp.name}-${comp.component}`,
    component: () => import('@plugins/' + comp.name + '/components/' + comp.component + '.vue')
  });
});
```

Including `@plugins/` in the string literal was very important, and so was including `.vue`, which I think prevents it from preloading backend-only js files I don't want in frontend.

I still have concerns about this plugin architecture when I transition to NPM modules, but it works for now.